# Ignore Mouse Input Event for the rest of the Frame/Cycle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

After I handle a MouseUp Event, I would like to disable if for this cycle.
Is there a way of editing this read-only variable, or disabling it after if fires?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
    Debug.Log("a"); 
    // What I am looking for        
    Input.MouseButtonUp = false;            
}
    
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
    // This should then no longer trace
    Debug.Log("b");         
}
```

I'm aware that in this case I could use an if/else switch. My problem is that the functions are in different classes.

Comment: Hello, in which context is the event called? WPF, WinForms, ... Do you have a .Handled-Property?

Comment: I'm listening `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` for it from the update method in an object that inherits MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Whoops, I over read the second part of the question. Um, I do not know. Does the Input Event have a Handled-Property? If yes, I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a coroutine.

```
bool canPress = true;
IENumerator DisableInput()
{
    canPress = false; 
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    canPress = true;
}




if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && canPress){
     Debug.Log("a");    
     Input.MouseButtonUp = false;            
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && canPress){
    // This should then no longer trace
    Debug.Log("b");         
}
```